# Organize a List on C# Importing it with StreamReader

Tags: c#

I was tasked to import a list (disorganized) on a .csv extension to the visual Studio, I had to reorganize it but had some difficulty, I hope someone can help me, this was asked on my job, it's just an exercicese but I can't make sense of it, here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader points = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\mycomputer\Desktop\points.csv"))
                {
                    int num = 0;
                    while (!points.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        if(num <= 7)
                        {
                            num++;
                            points.ReadLine();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        string Points = points.ReadLine();
                        char Delimitator = '"';
                            String[] substrings = Points.Split('"', ',');
                            foreach (var substring in substrings)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The arquive can't be read.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is: I'm stuck on the "foreach (var substring in substrings) {} " part, I have to encapsulate in on an Object.cs class, I'll link the .csv file that I have to organize right here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mZRUSNoK4EHXgN0SGehG1DUA5QfTS1C2

**EDIT** This is the class:

```
class Object
        {
            public string[] Stablishment { get; set; }
            public string[] Name { get; set; }
            public string[] CardNumber { get; set; }
            public string[] Autorization { get; set; }
            public string[] OperationDate { get; set; }
            public string[] Payment { get; set; }
            public string[] GrossValue { get; set; }
            public string[] AdministrationTax { get; set; }
            public string[] MoneyTransfer { get; set; }
            public string[] OperationDateAndHour { get; set; }
            public string[] SSN { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are a gob of columns in that file so we have no idea which ones you want.  If `I have to encapsulate in on an Object.cs class` means anything like *store to a `List<T>`*, you might want to look at CSV parsing libraries like CSV Helper: it can open, read, parse and store the data in a types collection.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: "Object.cs" sounds like a filename, not a class. If you have a class, put it in your question. If you are to create a class from the file, say so.

Comment: It's not an answer, but a suggestion. This becomes much easier if you split it up into two separate parts. First write something that reads a file into an array of strings (lines.) Then write something else that reads a takes a single string and does something with it. Then write something else that takes an array of strings and calls the "single string" method. As mentioned, once you break it up into smaller tasks you will likely find that there are existing classes or libraries that will do most of what you need.

Comment: @Plutonix I can't use anything else, I could use and ArrayList but all the "open, read, parse and store" has to be done by brute force and thinking lol, thx

Comment: @NetMage Yep, I edited and inserted the class there, I modified it to receive and Array, don't know if it's wrong yet, thx bro

Comment: @ScottHannen That's very cleaver, thank you very much for the ideia, I'll try do that, ty very much!

Answer (score 0):

The line you want to use is:
    foreach (string substring in substrings)
    {
        ... etc ...
    }
This will make other things easier to deal with.

Looking at your data file:...

You only have usable data lines when there are 11 columns after that "Split" operation, so you need to check the length of the "Points" array before doing much else.

Are you going to throw away the header line?

Are you going to throw away the descriptive text which precedes the header line?

Comment: About the header, yep, that is the idea, at least that was part of the task given. I got to use that "foreach (string substring in substrings) { ... etc ... }" but I'm stuck on what to do inside of it, I need to separate names, establishments, etc... as it it on the line 7 of the .csv (I'm sorry for it being on Portuguese).

Comment: The seventh line contains the information classification of the lines ahead (Establishments, Names, Numbers, etc..), so, I need to get each name for example to be encapsulated on a class Object in an ArrayList of the same name "public string[] Name { get; set; }" so I can pull it in the future ahead with all the information from the same stablishment and show it on the console organized.

Comment: And before I find the answer I would like to thank you for the help, I appreciate it very very much!